# how to look for a field in different tables in vb.net using query

Tags: sql, vb.net

I Have a query in which i want to search in all the table for a common field using query below ismy code----

```vb
   Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Try
            'Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim dbprovider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Taher\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
            Me.con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT * FROM **mba mca mscit** WHERE urno='" & TextBox2.Text & "';"
            Dim command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlquery, con)
            Dim reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
            con.ConnectionString = dbprovider
            con.Open()

            reader = command.ExecuteReader()
            reader.Read()
            TextBox1.Text = reader(1).ToString
            TextBox2.Text = reader(2).ToString
            TextBox3.Text = reader(3).ToString
            TextBox4.Text = reader(4).ToString
            TextBox5.Text = reader(5).ToString
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Not Found")
            con.Close()
        End Try
```

i want to search for urno in all the tables which have the fields in them with the same name....?

Comment: You could use system tables of the RDBMS you're using to get all of the tables names which have this column name 'urno' and then execute a separate SQL statement on each table.  (not an answer because I don't show you how to do it)

Comment: What you're doing right now is vulnerable to sql injection. This code is practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: it wont matter for the moment ....i just need away to tis

Comment: And that attitude is where security issues begin.

Comment: do appreciate your concern but its not going commercial so i think its ok....:)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tables mba, mca and mscit have the same columns, then

```
SELECT * FROM mba
WHERE urno=@urno
UNION
SELECT * FROM mca
WHERE urno=@urno
UNION
SELECT * FROM mscit
WHERE urno=@urno
```

and supply an SQL parameter (q.v.) for @urno

Comment: didn;t quite understand the sql parameter part q.v, for @urno and i have ms access as database...

Comment: @user1897472 "q.v." basically means "look it up". You could just subsitute your `& TextBox2.Text &`, but it starts to get messy when you do that.